# What would be the correct entity-relationship diagram for this CSV file?

Tags: database-design, erd

I received this from a customer and I was asked to model this as a database.

```
    Key Article number  color code  description price   action price    delivery    q1  size    color
    2800104 2   pants   Gaastra    8.00     1-3 working days    baby    104 gray
    00000002groe56  2   pants   Gaastra    8.00     1-3 working days    baby    56  green
    00000002groe62  2   pants   Gaastra    8.00     1-3 working days    baby    62  green
    00000002groe68  2   pants   Gaastra    8.00     1-3 working days    baby    68  green
    00000002groe74  2   pants   Gaastra    8.00     1-3 working days    baby    74  green
    00000002groe80  2   pants   Gaastra    8.00     1-3 working days    baby    80  green
    00000002groe86  2   pants   Gaastra    88.00        1-3 working days    baby    86  green
```

So far I detected a Color entity type, maybe a Category entity type (either q1attribute or Color Code attribute), and a Product entity type with attributes Key, Article Number, Description, Price and Action Price, maybe Delivery as well.

I would like to hear opinions if my analysis is correct or if I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have similar data model. It is not exactly as you expect. But surely it will help you to get start.

From the **CSV** file, the following columns can be derived:

```
Key         
Article_Number  
Color_Code  
Description 
Price
Action_Price
Delivery
Category
Size
Color
```

For the above mentioned table, the following model can be designed. Depends on your exact requirement, you may [normalize](http://www.rathishkumar.in/2016/01/what-is-database-normalization.html) this model or [denormalize](http://www.rathishkumar.in/2016/01/database-denormalization.html).
[image: Simple Product Data Model]

I hope this answer will help you.